# Error when running emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio on my computer (Windows 8) but when i tried to run a program i get the error:

"Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?"

I have tried almost all the emulators but am still getting this error or it won't even start.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Start the emulator first and then run the program.

Comment: Worked like a charm.I started the emulator first, then started the "choose running device" option from the Choose Device window.Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wait for the emulator to full start - takes a few minutes. Once it is fully started (UI on the emulator will change), it should work.

This might help you..

Comment: Yes, until the emulator fully starts, restart your application.

Comment: How do I know when the emulator is UI is fully started? You say that the emulator will change - but what does it change FROM, and what does it change TO? 

My emulator shows an "ANDROID" logo, which is shimmering from left to right. Does this mean the emulator is (A) fully started or (B) still waiting to "change"?