# Andorid Studio: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio, and created a test project with a test activity.
Other than that I touched nothing.

Whenever I try to run the app I get the following error:

Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

In the emulators list I do have an emulator already running under "Choose a running device":

Emulator unkkown Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

It is selected and I click "OK".

I googled the matter and followed the instructions of 3 topics, none solved the problem for me.

[could not access the package manager. is the system running while installing android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524185/could-not-access-the-package-manager-is-the-system-running-while-installing-and)

[Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running? - At Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526565/error-could-not-access-the-package-manager-is-the-system-running-at-android)

[Error when running emulator in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873618/error-when-running-emulator-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

please check if you have installed Bluestack. Bluestack runs its process in background .

Comment: Yes, Bluestacks is intalled.

Comment: Then close blue stack service from task manager i.e HD-Frontend service or else launch the bluestack properly

Comment: Closed. There's no longer an option under "Choose a running device".

When trying to lunch the Nexus emulator I get the following error:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: I removed Bluestacks from Startup and restarted my computer. When I try to run the app, the device Emulator unkkown Android 4.4.2 (API 19) appears under "Choose a running device", and the same error is thrown. Your suggestion seems irrelevant.